# Find the bounded orbits of the system $x'=y$, $y'=x+x^2-y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Consider
>   $$
> \frac{dx}{dt}=y,\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=x+x^2-y.
> $$
>   Describe the set of all bounded orbits. Hint, use $H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$.

The equilibria are 
$$
O_1=(0,0),~~~O_2=(-1,0).
$$

The linearization matrix of the system at $O_1$ is $A_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and so $O_1$ is a saddle. The linearization matrix of the system at $O_2$ is $A_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, hence $O_2$ is a stable equilibrium.

So, I know that at least $O_1$ and $O_2$ are bounded orbits. How can I determine all others?

I think candidates only can be some orbits that start in $O_1$ and end in $O_2$. But which ones?

Here is a phase portrait.

[image]

Comment: The system as written does not seem to be Hamiltonian, unless you drop the $-y$ term in the second equation.

Comment: Really? I am sure to wrote down the task correctly and the hint that the system is Hamiltonian with the given function, too.

Comment: You can check whether your $H$ is a Hamiltonian for the system or not.

Comment: You are right, The function H is not the Hamiltonian. Nonetheless, I edit the task.

Comment: In fact, the task does not say that H is the Hamiltonian. Was my fault.

Comment: A search for "phase plot online" would provide some online sofware to visualise the phase portrait for your system.

Comment: Added a phase portrait

Comment: Yes, there seems to be just one solution between the two equilibrium points ( below them), never reaching  any neither in the past nor in the future.  Baffling, what other points will be on that curve?

Comment: How do you see that there seems to be only solution between the two equilibria? I do not see that from the picture.